# Can I cut through blocking to install light fixture?

Tags: drywall, light-fixture, structural, studs, blocking

I am replacing a light fixture in a bathroom just under 7 feet up on the wall and behind the very shallow electrical box is a blocking 1x4. The fixture we are installing needs about 3 inches of depth.

Can I cut a section in this blocking so I can put in a deeper box? The ceiling is 8 1/2 feet up and it seems strange to put a support block up 7 feet. Is this maybe just for hanging things like mirrors and cabinets?

[image]

Comment: It depends on what the block is for.  Are you able to see behind it from the other room ?  Could you please post a zoomed out photo, so we can see what around that area ?

Comment: ... or see behind with a borescope camera.  They are cheap, useful, and fun.

Comment: Is there another bath on the other side of the wall?  The blocking may be for a shower drop ear there.

Comment: In what way does the fixture need that depth? If it's just a mounting stud, shorten it. Please revise to add more detail about the problem rather than your proposed solution.